# Multiple differential tranceivers on single bus

Tags: communication, differential, transmission-line, high-impedance

Im using a few moduls of rs422 tranceivers connected on single bus
Easy module has transciver with TX input, RX output power end differential pair output and input - but no EN pin to hold the transmission in high Z mode

What simple solutions can i do in my design to get multiple transcivers share the same bus and not disturb each other ?

Edit : the operation is master slave mode (one master that addresses single device , and only the master "care" for the device responce)
So electricly the slaves TX connected to masters RX
And same the other way around

Edit2 : i need a solution for implementing the high z in my design
Changing the transceiver is not an option

Comment: You should be using RS485 transceivers, not RS422.

Comment: Mr. White is right. My Data Transmission Design Seminar Book from TI also states: unidirectional communication, but you can connect 10 receivers to one transmitter...

Comment: @schnedan Check the edit

Comment: you still would need to build the high Z Stage by yourself. And this will take more time,space and money than just buy some RS485 chips.

Comment: @schnedan that is exactly what i need to think with you guys what whould be the best most elegant solution to build the high z ?

Answer (score 0):

> what would be the best most elegant solution.

Use RS-485. It's designed to handle multiple tx/rx on a single bus, one tx at a time so the transmitters have enable inputs. RS-422 is designed to use one tx per bus.

Comment: Check the second edit

Comment: It would help if you mention all your constraints up front. If you're using commercial RS-422 modules rather than designing to component level can you provide a link to the modules you are using? Google doesn't find anything useful with the description you gave.

Comment: It doesnt realy matter - im searching for simple and elegant external high z implementation... i could use 2 transistors on the output of each TX though im looking for may be simpler and more elegant solution